# how can i use sphinx with oscommerce website?

Tags: php, sphinx, oscommerce

I need to integrate sphinx with my oscommerce website but i dont understand how to start it.how to implement sphinx php api and use it with oscommrece php mysql queries.

I really appreciate any help I can get! Thanks!

Comment: You need to be more specific. What specific part are you having issue with? What have you tried so far? This seems just as relevent even to SO: http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Comment: barryhunter i mean should i have use sphinx queries instead of all osommerce select queries ?

Comment: Will probably have to use both. But it depends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use this URL FOR SPINIX http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/2.0.6/about.html

Thanx

Comment: thank you manish for your link but my question is how to implement sphinx with my oscommerce website?

Comment: Please Answer My Question...

Comment: hey jummy...You need to search in google website.

Comment: This URL: www.google.com will use for it.

Comment: No. No one can really answer such a horribly vague question. Like they say, "ask a silly question, get a silly answer"